# SQL - Formatting a result set and replacing text - code and pictures included

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-null

I'm having trouble formatting this result set. The columns vendor_address1 and vendor_address2 have the text NULL in them. I need to format the output like the picture. I have tried various case statements, the replace() function, etc. I initially thought the NULL text was a null value but then soon realized its actual text. The Pacific Bell vendor should have no spaces in the beginning. I was trying to remove the spaces with the LTRIM function (or that was my idea).

Here is my code:

```
SELECT vendor_name,
  LTRIM(REPLACE(vendor_address1, 'NULL', ' ')) || ', ' || 
  LTRIM(REPLACE(vendor_address2, 'NULL', ' ')) || ', ' ||
  vendor_city || ', ' || vendor_state || ' ' || vendor_zip_code
  AS "Complete Address"
FROM ap.vendors
WHERE vendor_name LIKE 'P%'
```

My Current Output

[image: My Current Output]

My Desired Output

[image]

Vendors Table
[image]

EDIT: I tried the suggestion below but got this result instead:
[image]

EDIT2: So I was able to figure it out. Here is the code I ended up using, in case anyone was wondering:

```
SELECT vendor_name,
   DECODE(vendor_address1, 'NULL', '', vendor_address1 || ', ') ||
   DECODE(vendor_address2, 'NULL', '', vendor_address2 || ', ') ||
   vendor_city || ', ' ||vendor_state || ' ' || vendor_zip_code AS 
"Complete Address"
FROM ap.vendors
WHERE vendor_name LIKE 'P%'
```

This gives the output that matches my "Desired Output"

Answer (score 0):

What you need is `NVL2()` function as you need **non-null** case such as

```
SELECT vendor_name,
       NVL2(TRIM(vendor_address1), TRIM(vendor_address1)||', ',null )||
       NVL2(TRIM(vendor_address2), TRIM(vendor_address2)||', ',null )|| 
       vendor_city || ', ' ||vendor_state || ' ' || vendor_zip_code AS "Complete Address"
  FROM ap.vendors
 WHERE vendor_name LIKE 'P%'
```

where `vendor_city`,`vendor_state` and `vendor_zip_code` columns are presumed to be non-null always. The `vendor_addresses` should be suffixed with a comma if either of them is non-null.

Btw, `'NULL'` is just a literal, but not identical to `null`(or `NULL`)

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/yMcmeroh)</kbd>

Comment: So when I do that this is what I get. https://imgur.com/a/372W2Dq The "NULL" in the vendor_address1 & vendor_address2 is the actual string "NULL", not a null value.

Comment: seems like the image link is corrupted @fice, I can't see the content. Btw, it's better to share the sample data as text rather than images, even within the question(although I can see them, hard to copy and reproduce the case).

Comment: I apologize! I'm new to Stack Overflow and I'm not sure how to share the sample data as text. I'm using SQL Developer. I did edit my initial post with the result of your suggestion. I will try to give as much info as I can.

Comment: No problem @fice :), I've added a demo, check out please. Btw, you quoted `NULL` again, just get rid of them...  [  *'NULL' is just a literal, but not identical to null(or NULL)* ]

Comment: So I copied and pasted the initial code you wrote and the ouput was the same as my edit.  The text NULL is the literal text/string "NULL".

Comment: What do you see whenever replace those `null`s with `''` --> two single quotes .. ? @fice for the last arguments of the `NVL2` functions similar to https://dbfiddle.uk/yxxV-ShK

Comment: I replaced the last argument of NVL2 with two single quotes and the result was still the same as my edit.

Comment: If you were curious as to the solution, you can see my EDIT 2.

Comment: @fice you're still confusing `'NULL'` with `NULL`. Can you please check out [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/3ol7HR9b). Yes, `DECODE()` is used for conditional logic but using `DECODE()` is not needed for this case as `NVL2()` already handles cases with null against non-null arguments.